# Webgl support for newer android phones

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webgl

I plan on creating a javascript app which will have some image manipulation needed. I have tested it on a regular browser without webgl and it is very slow compared to a phone which supports webgl. This is an important feature, but not crucial to the application (if ~80% of users could use it that would be fine). Some devices are blacklisted from using webgl (https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists) but I am wondering is it safe to say as a general rule of thumb that newer phones will support webgl?

Comment: If you use opegles 1.1 spec you can run webgl on lot of devices. 
I suggest chromium for android webview . Webgl supported long time ago , webrtc is new feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Crosswalk Webview. This may help avoid unexpected platform issues.

https://gist.github.com/butelo/9365587

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html

https://medium.com/@tegon/webgl-and-es6-in-android-webview-with-crosswalk-d6880eb5e8fc#.wn9tnshhm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes crosswalk is great for browser issues, but some phones graphic cards can't handle it. I am unsure though if new phones will will be built to be able to run webgl?

Comment: no one can predict the future. It seems unlikely to me any company would make a new phone that doesn't support WebGL as it would probably also not support the majority of popular games. At the same time some company is about to release non-smartphone old style feature phones. There's no way to know what companies will do.